# Getting Undefined Sign-On URL error while redirecting from Azure to my app

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-java-sdk

I'm integrating Azure AD login authentication to my web app. I have created an account in azure development portal and registered my app details. while registering I didn't provide value for Application ID URI. but provided other details such as redirect URLs, type: web app etc

my app URL -> https://my-sample-app/my.dashboard/

my redirect url is ->https://my-sample-app/my.dashboard/ws/aad/callback/

Note : ws that comes after my app url is the servlet adapter configured

Name of the app regist

In my application, I have written the code logic to receive the azure returning tokens through a web service end point ("/aad/callback/"). my app is a java web app so used Azure java SDK

when i hit the "http://portal.office.com" and provide the credentials registered in azure , i can see my app as an icon in the office365 landed page. once i click my app icon then i'm redirected and got an error that

```
Something went wrong...
You cannot access this application because it has been misconfigured. Contact your IT department and include the following information:
Undefined Sign-On URL for application "My Dashboard (Dev)"
```

Can someone help what went wrong here ? I can see that the app id URI is not configured during the app registration in azure. is that the reason ?

Answer (score 2):

The Sign-on URL is different from the app ID URI.

App ID URI is used to ide tify APIs.

The Sign-on URL / Home page URL is put in links like the Office front page or the My Apps portal. 
You can set it in the application registration's Branding tab.

Comment: Fine but any clue why I'm getting the message "Undefined Sign-On URL for application" ?

Comment: Maybe you didn't specify a home page URL?